# Javascript 2D array to 1D array and interval

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 300px * 300px image. I also have some specific pixels every 100px in every direction (to 16 specific pixels in total).

```
                      0      1      2       <-- IntervalX
                    ______ ______ ______
                0  |      |      |      |
                   |______|______|______|    
                1  |      |      |      | 
                   |______|______|______| 
                2  |      |      |      | 
                   |______|______|______| 
                ^
                 IntervalY
```

I want to put every pixels (except the specific ones) in blocks bounded by the specific pixels, but defined by the pixels value in a 1D array, not 2D array.

```
 const gridX = width / (trueX - 1);
 const gridY = width / (trueY - 1);
```

//Loop for every pixel:

```
 intervalX = Math.floor((pixel[inc].x) / gridX);
 intervalY = Math.floor((pixel[inc].y) / gridY);
 //Implementing formula for transforming from 1D array to 2D array : (y * width + x) = item number
 //All leftmost known pixels start from a "zero" value, so we do not need to substract 1
 let isNotFirstArray;
 if (intervalX == 0)
    isNotFirstArray = 0;
 else
    isNotFirstArray = 1;    
 p1 = pixel[intervalY * gridY * 299 + intervalX * gridX - isNotFirstArray];
 p2 = pixel[intervalY * gridY * 299 + (intervalX + 1) * gridX - 1];
 p3 = pixel[(intervalY + 1) * gridY * 299 + intervalX * gridX - isNotFirstArray];
 p4 = pixel[(intervalY + 1) * gridY * 299 + (intervalX + 1) * gridX - 1];
 pixel[inc].value = Math.round(bilinearInterpolate(p1, p2, p3, p4, j, i));
 inc++;
```

The problem is the values for the specific pixels are not calculated correctly. The Y values are correct, but the X are not.

Later edit:
The error is like this: the coordinates of the specific pixels are correct on the Y axis, but not on the X axis. They are shifted for the inner intervals with 100px*(max intervals - current interval).

Comment: your constant "gridY" shouldn't it be "const gridY = height / (trueY - 1);" instead of "width" ?

Comment: Yes, your are right. This doesn not fix the problem unfortunatly because for testing I used 300*300px which means height = width.

Comment: Yes I did notice that, hence comment not an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get that right, you would like to »filter-out« some of the pixels, which appear at some interval in x and y direction?

```
const img = <image array>,
      imgWidth = 600,
      gridX = 150,
      gridY = 200;

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  let x = i % imgWidth,
      y = Math.floor(i / imgWidth);

  if (!(x % gridX == 0 || y % gridY == 0)) {
    result.push(input[i])
  } 
}
```

That should filter out all the indexes which are as special as you said. It remains an array of pixels of an image with the a width.